# Can I modify a signal within a process if it's also in the sensitivity list in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I understand that changes to a signal within a process would take place  at the end of the process.
 I need the process to modify signals that are in it's sensitivity list and then reevaluate;

something like

```
signal a: std_logic;
signal b: std_logic;
process(a,b) begin
if(b='1') then
a<='0';
end if;
end process;
```

Comment: Yes. Your yes/no question snippet doesn't have the structure described in the title. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.2 Wait statement for the rules for constructing a sensitivity list.  In -2008 you can use the reserved word `all` to construct the sensitivity list from every signal evaluated in any process statement. Your snippet doesn't evaluate a. You'd get the process to resume needlessly once every time a is assigned and a is already '0'. An assignment schedules an update, if the value changes you get an event (14.7.3.4 Signal update) and the process resumes (14.7.5.3 Simulation cycle).

Comment: You are probably looking for a variable in a process. Variables are updated immediately, but not at the next wait statement. Please not a process with sensitivity ist is equivalent to a process with a `wait on <signallist>;` before the `end process;`

Comment: If you update a signal in the sensitivity list, you will cause the process to be re-evaluated. It is possible to cause an infinite loop like this and cause a simulator to hit the iteration limit (and fail) or create a logic loop in real hardware.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now :)